Firebase hosting not working for angular app
After lots of development locally using ng serve to interact with my angular app, I decided to add firebase hosting. After completing the setup, I clicked on the web link, which never loaded. Using 'firebase emulators: start' in the terminal yielded a page blank page, but with a working title and background color. In the console, I found these 2 errors:

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.Understand this errorAI

and

main-BG7YVEIX.js:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.


Here is my build section of angular.json
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/goalApp",
    "index": "src/index.html",
    "browser": "src/main.ts",
    "baseHref": "/",
    "polyfills": [
      "zone.js"
    ],
    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "assets": [
      "src/assets",
      {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "public"
        
      }
    ],
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [],
    "server": "src/main.server.ts",
    "prerender": true,
    "ssr": {
      "entry": "server.ts"
    }
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "budgets": [
        {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "1MB",
          "maximumError": "1.5MB"
        },
        {
          "type": "anyComponentStyle",
          "maximumWarning": "4.5kB",
          "maximumError": "5kB"
        }
      ],
      "outputHashing": "all"
    },
    "development": {
      "optimization": false,
      "extractLicenses": false,
      "sourceMap": true
    }
  },
  "defaultConfiguration": "production"
},

and my firebase.json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/goalApp",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/browser/index.csr.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}

I looked through this thread. But none of the answers seem to work for me. Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html".
Since my title is being rendered, I assume the build knows the base folder and the other errors are something else.
What do I need to change to get my app rendered?
